# How to remove alpha numeric characters from a string within an array using javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, string

I need help removing alpha numeric chars within a string in a specific array location. Here is my Code:

```
function cleanTab(array) {
 array = array.split("\t");
 array = array[4].replace(/\W/g, '');

 return array;
}
```

So I split the full string given to me by a tab char.
then I want to take that new array and remove the non alpha numeric chars from the string in array spot 4. It throws an error "cannot read property 'replace' of undefined". But if I try it on array[0] it works. I dont know

Comment: Are there actually five elements in the array?

Comment: there is 16. if I return array[4] it returns the value as expected but wont let me run the replace method on it.

Comment: I simplified it to `console.log((function cleanTab(string) { return string.split("\t")[4].replace(/\W/g, ''); })("\tHello\tworld\tfoo\tbar./';\tworld"));` and it seems to do what it should. What is the expected output?

Comment: I try that and its still throwing an error.

Comment: Please show your input. To be able to access array index **4**, you need to have at least 4 tabs in that input, so 5 or more tab separated elements.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should access you array index first 
If you want to change something on the string at array index 4
it should be array[4] = array[4].stingmethod.

Example

```
var array = ["0", "1", "2", "3", "test123!@#$"];
array[4] = array[4].replace(/[^a-z0-9]/gmi, " ").replace(/\s+/g, " ");
console.log(array[4]);
```

Comment: I tried that and it still doesnt work. What am i missing?

Comment: can you give an example of what the string looks like and how you want it to look in the end?

Answer (score 0):

`.split()` will return an array. Try looping through after the split, and use `.join()` if you need to turn it back into a string